# How to filter bs4 web scraping results by text and tag in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<p class="text-muted text-small">
    Directors:
<a href="/name/nm6676487/?ref_=ttls_li_dr_0">Jeff Rowe</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm5859016/?ref_=ttls_li_dr_1">Kyler Spears</a>
                 <span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm9368660/?ref_=ttls_li_st_0">Micah Abbey</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm8366356/?ref_=ttls_li_st_1">Shamon Brown Jr.</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm7751235/?ref_=ttls_li_st_2">Nicolas Cantu</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm4054776/?ref_=ttls_li_st_3">Brady Noon</a>
    </p>
```

I'm trying to web scrape the strings located in the html above. I can't quite figure out how to separate the strings by either "Stars:" or |.

For reference, these are movie directors and actors, and obviously each movie's html block like this can have varying numbers of directors/actors. I've tried to use ChatGPT or Bard. This is my first larger python project, so I'm very new to everything. Appreciate any advice or guidance.

Comment: This is really poorly designed HTML, since the HTML structure doesn't mirror the semantics. `Directors:` and `Stars:` should each be in their own DIV or SECTION.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to search for previous text `Stars:`. If the search is successful then you have a star, otherwise director:

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<p class="text-muted text-small">
    Directors:
<a href="/name/nm6676487/?ref_=ttls_li_dr_0">Jeff Rowe</a>,
<a href="/name/nm5859016/?ref_=ttls_li_dr_1">Kyler Spears</a>
                 <span class="ghost">|</span>
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm9368660/?ref_=ttls_li_st_0">Micah Abbey</a>,
<a href="/name/nm8366356/?ref_=ttls_li_st_1">Shamon Brown Jr.</a>,
<a href="/name/nm7751235/?ref_=ttls_li_st_2">Nicolas Cantu</a>,
<a href="/name/nm4054776/?ref_=ttls_li_st_3">Brady Noon</a>
    </p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

directors, stars = [], []
for a in soup.select("p a"):
    is_star = a.find_previous(string=re.compile("Stars:"))
    if is_star:
        stars.append(a.text)
    else:
        directors.append(a.text)

print("Directors:")
print(*directors, sep="\n")
print()
print("Stars:")
print(*stars, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
Directors:
Jeff Rowe
Kyler Spears

Stars:
Micah Abbey
Shamon Brown Jr.
Nicolas Cantu
Brady Noon
```

---

Other solution:

```py
out = {}
for a in soup.select("p a"):
    role = a.find_previous(string=re.compile(r"^\s*\S+:", flags=re.M))
    if role:
        out.setdefault(role.text.strip("\n :"), []).append(a.text)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "Directors": ["Jeff Rowe", "Kyler Spears"],
    "Stars": ["Micah Abbey", "Shamon Brown Jr.", "Nicolas Cantu", "Brady Noon"],
}
```